# How to prevent android system from creating folders on internal storage

Tags: file-system

Is it possible to prevent Android from creating additional folders inside **/data/app/**

That is, this is the folder where (user-level) apps¹ are installed. So making the *whole thing* recursively unwriteable will mostly likely break the apps and that's not really what I'd like. (although if you know how to do that I don't mind testing it out) But my primary reason is that I want to prevent any folders from being created there. Specifically the temporary folders that Download Manager is creating there. This is part of my quest to take control over the Download Manager. I can't replace it, so I'm trying different approaches to, well, manage the Manager.

Additional info:
Device is rooted. Storage is internal. Android: v6.0.1, ROM: MIUI 8.5.3.0

---

¹ <sub>meaning the apps (APKs) themselves, I'm not speaking about `/data/data/<package_name>/*`</sub>

Comment: @Izzy I have access to a TouchWiz KitKat, and it's still got the APKs listed one after the other. I guess that the folders started popping up on Lollipop.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the edits! :) Added phone info

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you are trying to achieve? This might actually be an XY problem. If Download Manager is creating *temporary* folders then what's the issue with that? Moreover, what exactly is the issue that you thought to stop creation of new folders?

Comment: @Firelord I'm trying to control all installations that take place on the device which are triggered via Download Manager (I mean not sure exactly about the details but it seems to go through it) So that I would be able to install only the apps that I manually download. This might not be the best approach, but the thing first creates temporary folder while it's downloading and there seems to be only one concurrent download allowed. So I thought maybe use that somehow. That is I'm trying to stop automatic updates/downloads

Comment: If you want to stop automatic updates why not you go to play store>settings>auto update apps and set it to " do not auto-update apps" this what are you asking is playing with fire.

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I meant System auto-updates (sorry ran out of space above). For normal apps that works, but for things like Google Play Services, Play Store etc, it just gets updated automatically. Been trying to disable this for quite some time (without losing app store)

Comment: Wait you want to stop play services and play store updates or Android system updates or both?

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје I want to disable everything that gets installed automatically. Except normal apps - they can be on/offed inside the Google Play app. Also I'm not talking about the System as in ROM/OTA updates.

Comment: Ok, first may I ask why you want to do that? To disable Google play services and play store auto update you can try to set "restrict background data" for play store (maybe even play services but that would probably cause more troubles, especially if you use play games and any other Google app) but keep in mind that than if you want to download/update app you will must stay in play store until process is finished. It's not ideal solution (it's more like crippling ).

Comment: @ЈеднорукиКрстивоје Well that's why I want to disable auto-update and not these components themselves. I could also use a firewall to block them from internet. Also I can remove Download Manager & Play store from the phone. But then I won't be able to download new apps from Play store. (there are other stores, but I either wouldn't trust them or they're incomplete)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to prevent creation of new files/folders inside a particular folder is to use the chattr +i command. Using "+i" makes it immutable, preventing changes by anyone, including su, until you do -i .

so doing: **chattr +i /data/app**

and then running: `mkdir /data/app/blah` will fail
but `mkdir /data/app/com.android.vending-1/blah` will work fine

Comment: Good job I was just about to post this.

Comment: Thanks! ;) I think chattr is one of the lesser known/used Linux commands out there. It's the first time I ever had the need for it.

Answer (score -1):

With chmod 744 as a root you ONLY can read/write in the folder /data/app (anyone else is readonly) but I wouldnt want to do this because apps are there located too. But you can only restrict user 1000 which is the system (i think) by doing

cd /

su 1000

chmod -wx /data/app/ -Rv (-R is recursively an -v is verbose)

**ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY THAT THIS IS NOT HARMFULL**

Comment: Well, I don't want to touch the existing folders because as you mentioned this is where the Apps are. I want to prevent creation of New folders inside /data/app folder.

Comment: 1. sorry for the late answer: you cant disallow the system anything without risking a bootloop, factory reset, etc. If you want to diable bloatware this way you could just uninstall it with pm uninstall

Comment: Well, basically if one goes into the terminal mode with a root access, bootloop can happen ;) Removing bloatware is the least of my problems, got an automated script that does it. I'm trying to prevent Google from installing its apps like the Play Store update etc. So I thought maybe I block a folder it uses while downloading the app. I found a folders for new/updates to regular apps but it's smarter than that...